Show 7 is a generator of $\left(\mathbb{Z} \backslash p \mathbb{Z} \right)^*$ given that it is a quadratic noresidue.
I would like to prove that $7$ is a generator for $\left(\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} \right)^*$ for $p$ a Fermat prime, i.e. of the form $p = 2^{2^n} + 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Earlier in the exercise, I have shown that $7$ is a quadratic nonresidue of $p$. My question is, how can I conclude that $7$ is a generator of $\left(\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} \right)^*$, using this fact? Some things that I have tried to use:

A generator $g \in \left(\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z} \right)^*$ must have order $\phi(p) = p-1 = 2^{2^n}$. Using this fact, the order of a generator $g$ must satisfy $g^{2^{2^{n}}} =1 \mod p$ and $g^m \neq 1 \mod p$ for $1\leq m < 2^{2^n}$.

If $7$ were a quadratic residue, then $7 = a^2$ for some $a \in \left(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} \right)^*$ and hence $7^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = (a^2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = a^{p-1} \overset{\text{Euler}}{=} 1 \mod p$.


I understand why a quadratic residue cannot be a generator, using the reasoning of point 2. However, I do not see how I can conclude that a number is a generator, in this case, but also in the more general case. Can someone explain to me how I can conclude 7 is a generator, and in what cases a number is a generator?

Show that the numbers of quadratic non-residues and of primitive roots are equal.

Since $7$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$, it follows that $7^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$. Since $p = 2^{2^n} + 1$, this implies $7^{2^{2^n -1}} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, which implies that $7^{2^i} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for all $i \leq 2^n-1$. Thus ${\rm ord}\ 7 \pmod{p} = 2^{2^n} = p-1$ and hence $7$ is a generator $\pmod{p}$.
Edit: More generally, this also shows that any quadratic non-residue is a generator $\pmod{p}$ when $p$ is a Fermat prime.
